# Ensure a class implements at least one method

Tags: php, oop

**Scenario**

In no way is this real, so take the example with a grain of salt. It's meant to be an easy way to convey a scenario. With that said, let's say we have the following class definitions.

```
interface iVehicle {
   public function getDescriptionFormat1();
   public function getDescriptionFormat2(); 
}

class VehicleDescription {
   ...
}

class TruckDescription extends VehicleDescription implements iVehicle {
  ... 
}

class CarDescription extends VehicleDescription implements iVehicle {
  ...
}
```

**Problem**

Classes CarDescription and TruckDescription may implement one or both of the description formats. Overriding both methods in *both classes* seems wrong when only *one* would be required. What is the proper way to implement such a restriction? Alternatively, you can attempt to sell me on the fact that it's a bad design decision.

***EDIT-***
i'm afraid I was a little too vague with my example. My apologies. The two descriptions are more or less different data structures, not strings. One might return an array representing a detailed description 3 columns in length, the other might return a more basic description table with 2 columns

Comment: You can use traits and abstract methods in them. So Truck will use truckTrait and will have to implement only its methods, and Car will use only carTrait and will have to implement its methods. But this also looks ugly.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear- Both formats CAN be implemented by CarDescription and TruckDescription.

Comment: Well, then why not just declare them in `VehicleDescription` with empty bodies and implement when necessary?

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov indeed that is an option, but then I have no way of enforcing future classes to implement one of those methods. An Error or warning would be great.

Comment: You can also throw an exception or trigger error in method in class whose children must implement method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use one method for both cases and give it a parameter to determine how it should behave, e.g.

```
interface iVehicle {
    public function getDescription($Format);
}

class CarDescription extends VehicleDescription implements iVehicle {
    public function getDescription($Format) {
        switch ($Format) {
            case 1:
                // Do what needs to be done
                break;
            case 2:
                // Do what needs to be done
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Error');
                break;
    }
}
```

or you use two interfaces and the class implements the appropriate interface for it (or both.)

```
interface iVehicle1 {
    public function getDescriptionFormat1();
}
interface iVehicle2 {
    public function getDescriptionFormat2();
}

// Let's skip forward

class CarDescription extends VehicleDescription implements iVehicle1, iVehicle2 {
    // ...
}
```

Of course, you'd still have to use different method names in the latter case, in case that class would implement both interfaces.

Comment: I like the second example. It's about as close to what I'm looking for thus far. I would just have to check that class_implements() one of three different interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just use a single `getDescriptionFormat()` method and provide the appropriate implementations for the different subclasses of the `VehicleDescription` class.

**EDIT**

I just read your comment to your question, that the classes CAN implement both methods. If that is what you want, your example is already ok. One thing you could do is provide empty implementations in the `VehicleDescription` class.

As for how to ensure that at least one of the methods is implemented in this scenario, I do not think this is possible, but correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

An interface can be considered to be a contract. Any class that implements that interface guarantees that it will provide the functions specified.

However, it is entirely up to the implementing class how it actually does this. In your example `TruckDescription` and `CarDescription` may need to return different description formats for various reasons and so implement `getDescriptionFormat1()` & `getDescriptionFormat2()` in different ways.

Basically that means that you probably just need `getDescriptionFormat()` in the interface and then the implementing classes can implement the function as required.

It sounds as if you should standardise what is returned. Perhaps a Format Class that can encapsulate the description? I'm just guessing now as I don't know any details, but I think that's what I'd be considering.

Comment: All very true, but i'm afraid I was a little too vague with my example. My apologies. The two descriptions are more or less different formats of data, not strings. One might return an array representing a detailed description 3 columns in length, the other might return a more basic description table with 2 columns.

Comment: Then maybe you should standardise what is returned? Perhaps a Format Class that can encapsulate the description? I'm just guessing now as I don't know any details, but I think that's what I'd be considering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would tackle this one.

```
interface Describable {
   public function getDescription(); 
}

interface Sellable {
    public function getPrice();
}

// abstract class - can't create an instance but can hold shared methods and property definitions
abstract class Vehicle implements Describable, Sellable {
    abstract public function getDescription();

    // this can't be overloaded
    final public function getPrice(){
        // code for get price
    }
    public function getColorOptions(){
        // this can be overloaded
    }
}

// concrete class that just uses the abstracts' definitions
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public function getDescription(){
        // overload for cars
    }
}

// concrete class that overloads one of the properties
class Truck extends Vehicle {
    public function getDescription(){
        // overload for trucks
    } 
}


class FlyingCar extends Car {
    public function getDescription(){
        // Flying cars need a whole new description
    }

}
```

Basically this show a method that must be overloaded (the getDescription by virtue of it being defined as abstract)

one that can't be overloaded (the getPrice by virtue of it being defined final)

and one that is defined on the abstract that you can either overload or use the default implementation.